# How to write query using spring-data-solr which return list of all values of specific field

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I want to write a query that gets list of all values of one field in the documents (no conditions at all).
I try the following code:

```
@Query(fields = { "car_company_s" })
List<Car> findAllCarCompeny();
```

But it didn't work, I got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllCarCompeny found for type Car!
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a ["Term"](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-terms-component.html). Basically it returns all values of a field. You need solr template, as said in [description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#solr.misc.terms) .
Example we are using:

```
    @Resource
    private SolrTemplate solrTemplate;
    ...     
    query = SimpleTermsQuery.queryBuilder()
                .fields(key)
                .prefix(startsWith.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) // we have some search prefix
                .sort(TermsOptions.Sort.INDEX)
                .build();
    
    TermsPage page = solrTemplate.queryForTermsPage(query);
    Iterable<TermsFieldEntry> terms = page.getTermsForField(key);
```

Terms are basically your values. Note, that you have to optimize core to remove values, that are from already deleted documents.